# How to prevent large file upload from server side

Tags: java, tomcat, file-upload, ddos, denial-of-service

I am looking to prevent my application from DoS attacks of the type `resource consumption`. It means an attacker can consume the server resources such as memory & disc capacity by uploading large files into the server.

I wish to know if its possible to check the incoming files for metadatas such as size and cancel the upload once a limit is reached. Otherwise an attacker may upload a 20 GB file to the server and if the server waits for the upload to complete to do the validation, then even before the upload completes, my server might have been flooded with such large files.

I wish to know how to do this with Java. I am using Apache/coyote 1.1.

---

Update:

I have found a solution in PHP as follows.

```
post_max_size integer
    Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload.
    To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize.
    If memory limit is enabled by your configure script, memory_limit also
    affects file uploading. Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger
    than post_max_size. When an integer is used, the value is measured in bytes.
    Shorthand notation, as described in this FAQ, may also be used. If the size
    of post data is greater than post_max_size, the $_POST and $_FILES
    superglobals are empty [...]

max_file_uploads integer
    The maximum number of files allowed to be uploaded simultaneously. Starting
    with PHP 5.3.4, upload fields left blank on submission do not count towards
    this limit.
```

Are there any substitutes for this in Java?

Comment: I think you should probably check on file size on client size and restrict uploads if it exceeds ideal size. Metadata on files at server side would be available when the file is transferred to server.

Comment: Client side validations can be easily bypassed by an attacker by tricks like disabling javascript. I would like to know whether there exist any methods to checks the file status during upload and act accordingly.

Comment: Instead of sending one big file, one can send 100k small files. Thats not fortifing you security at all.

Comment: That we can prevent by other methods like IP restriction and all. I am looking for this specific solution.

Comment: You cannot prevent dos attacks using software at all...

Comment: Refer: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmhal.html for limiting the upload file size

Comment: @ManoNamo I am not sure whether that is checking for the **incoming** file. I think its checking the **temporarily stored** file.

Comment: @AnonymousPlatypus AFAIK we need to rely on client side for getting the file size before it is uploaded. I will post my findings soon.

Comment: @ManoNamo  Thats sad. Anything checked on the client side can be tampered by an attacker.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a soltution from PHP. Please have a look at it also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can measure the size of uploading files by following means,

1. Client side (with HTML5, JSP, JS etc.,)
2. Dynamic measuring during upload (Container level)
3. Measuring after upload is over (Container level)

Since it is possible to tweak/hack #1 implementation. It is good to rely on #2. [MultipartConfig](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmhal.html) has the capability to interrupt file upload when the limit is reached (falling under #2).

Note:

1. You could use multipart config either as annotation (or) as servlet
   configuration element in the web.xml file

Answer (score 1):

https://www.netroby.com/view.php?id=3585, see if it's feasible for you to limit the file upload size.

Comment: Does this method check the incoming file? It won't be useful if the check takes place once the upload is completed.

Comment: This configuration is part of web.xml which gets deployed to your server along with application, it tells your server what size of file upload this application can handle, many servers support this kind of configuration at server or application level. Check your server configurations if it allows it at server level else you will need to configure it through your web.xml,  this will check incoming file for it's validity against the size limit configured for your server or app

Comment: Thank you for this. I have upvoted the answer. I will mark it as accepted if any other better methods are not populated.